# Not able to enter Email ID and Password in a Bootstrap dropdown (without frame) using selenium with java for website "https://qa01.pdng.pepsico.com/"

Tags: html, selenium

Below is the HTML code for which I need to Enter Email ID and Password which are the input fields as `id="j_username"` and `id="j_password"`.
There is no frame in this code so I cannot use it.

```
ul class="nav__links nav__links--shop_info">
<li class="logged_in js-logged_in hide">Welcome Anonymous</li>
<li>
    <div class="row">
    <div class="nav__left no-space col-sm-5 col-md-5 col-lg-7">
    <div class="site-search pull-right">
<div class="navSearchBox">
<div class="yCmsComponent">
<div class="ui-front">
<form name="search_form_SearchBox" method="get" action="/pepsico/en/USD/search/">
    <div class="input-group">
<input type="text" class="form-control js-site-search-input ui-autocomplete-input" name="text" aria-autocomplete="list" value="" maxlength="100" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search" data-options="{&quot;autocompleteUrl&quot; : &quot;/pepsico/en/USD/search/autocomplete/SearchBox&quot;,&quot;minCharactersBeforeRequest&quot; : &quot;3&quot;,&quot;waitTimeBeforeRequest&quot; : &quot;500&quot;,&quot;displayProductImages&quot; : true}">

    <span class="input-group-btn"> <button class="btn btn-link" type="submit">
<span class="sr-only">Search</span> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span>
    </button>
    </span>
    </div>
</form>
<ul class="ui-autocomplete ui-front ui-menu ui-widget ui-widget-content" id="ui-id-2" tabindex="0" style="display: none;"></ul></div>
</div></div>
    </div>
    </div>
    <div class=" no-space col-sm-7 col-md-7 col-lg-5">
    <div class="loginDD col-md-offset-1 col-md-3">
    <span class="myAccount"> 
    <span class="yCmsComponent">
        <span class="myAccountArrow" aria-hidden="true"> 
                    <span class="zeplin-arrow-dropdown zeplin-arrow"></span>
                                                </span>
        <span class="navSection hidden-xs"> 
    <a class="collapsed " href="javascript:void(0)" id="loginDown" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Sign In menu"> 
        <span class="myAccountIcon" aria-hidden="true">
    <span class="fa fa-user"></span></span>
 <span class="displayName">Hello,</span>
                <span class="userfname">Login/Register</span>
                        </a>
    <div class="login_overlay display-none" style="display: block;">
    <form id="loginForm" action="/pepsico/en/USD/j_spring_security_check" method="post" novalidate="novalidate"><div id="loginSpinner" class="spinner display-none">
    <span id="spinnerMessage"></span>
    <img src="/_ui/desktop/common/images/spinner.gif" alt="Spinner">
</div>
<div class="message-box  hide js-equipment-warning-msg" aria-hidden="true">
<div class="alert alert-warning">
    <span class="fa fa-exclamation-triangle" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="js-message message">Hey! Please login to access equipment services</span>
</div>
</div>
<div class="email-block">
    <div class="form-group ">
<label class="control-label " for="j_username">
            Email</label> 
<input id="j_username" name="j_username" class=" form-control" aria-required="true" type="text" value=""></div>
        </div>
        <div class="password-block js-password-block">
            <div class="form-group ">
            <label class="control-label " for="j_password">
            Password</label> 
        <div class="pwdBlock">
  <input id="j_password" name="j_password" class="form-control password js-password" aria-required="true" type="password" value="" autocomplete="off"></div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Post the code you're using that doesn't work. See the Help Center for how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Apart from what @MihaiChelaru mentioned you need to update the question with the _Selenium Language Binding Art_ are you using e.g. _Java_ / _Python_ / _C#_ / _NodeJS_

Comment: Yeah i am using Java with Selenium and below is code that does not work

Comment: WebDriver driver= new FirefoxDriver();
  driver.get("https://pepsicopartners.com");
  driver.manage().window().maximize();
  
  driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@id='loginDown']")).click();
  
  driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"main\"]/header/nav[2]/div/div[2]/div[3]/ul/li[2]/div/div[2]/div[1]/span/span/span[2]/div/form/div[3]/div/input[1]")).sendKeys("Abhishek@cognizant.com");
  driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='j_password']")).sendKeys("P@ssw0rd123");

Comment: I am getting "No Such Element Exception" for the last two lines also there is no Frame in the HTML code so that i can use Switch To frames. Can you please help me to find correct code.

Comment: Did you just post your password to a public discussion site?

Answer (score 0):

URL https://qa01.pdng.pepsico.com/ seems to be unreachable, so I tried login on https://pepsicopartners.com/ and following piece is working just fine:

```
WebDriverWait wait5s = new WebDriverWait(driver,5);

driver.get("https://pepsicopartners.com/");
WebElement lnk_goto_login = wait5s.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.id("loginDown")));
lnk_goto_login.click();
WebElement email = driver.findElement(By.id("j_username"));email.sendKeys("Abhishek@cognizant.com");
WebElement pwd = driver.findElement(By.id("j_password"));pwd.sendKeys("P@ssw0rd123");
WebElement accept_ToU = driver.findElement(By.id("terms"));accept_ToU.click();
WebElement btn_login = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"loginForm\"]/button"));btn_login.click();
Thread.sleep(5000);
```

Sure I can not login, but reach on all nessessary elements, successfuly send credetials and hit the login button.